# How to set background image in three.js with Next.js 14 of public folder

Tags: next.js, three.js

I am using latest next.js 14 with app router and latest three library

**Here is my code**

**app/page.js**

```
'use client'
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import * as three from "three"
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls"

export default function Home() {
  const containerref = useRef()
  let stars = "../public/stars.jpg"
  useEffect(() => {
    const renderer = new three.WebGLRenderer()
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    containerref.current?.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
    const scene = new three.Scene()
    const light = new three.AmbientLight({ color: 0xffffff })
    scene.add(light)
    const camera = new three.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000)
    const orbit = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
    camera.position.set(-10, 30, 30);
    orbit.update()
    const planeGeometry = new three.PlaneGeometry(30, 30)
    const planeMaterial = new three.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, side: three.DoubleSide })
    const plane = new three.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial)
    plane.rotation.x = Math.PI * -0.5;
    scene.add(plane)
    const gridHelper = new three.GridHelper(30)
    scene.add(gridHelper)
    const loader = new three.TextureLoader();
    loader.load('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1205301/pexels-photo-1205301.jpeg', function (texture) {
      scene.background = texture;
    });
    const animate = () => {
      renderer.render(scene, camera)
    }
    renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate)
  }, [])
  return (
    <div ref={containerref} />
  )
}
```

I am trying to add a background and it's working fine when I give a link of the image but not working when I am trying to set background to an image inside my public folder.